# Does spark caching required on the last common part of 2 actions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My code:

```
df1 = sql_context.sql("select * from table1") #should I cache here?
df2 = sql_context.sql("select * from table2") #should I cache here?
df1 = df1.where(df1.id == '5')
df1 = df1.where(df1.city == 'NY')
joined_df = df1.join(df2, on = "key") # should I cache here?
output_df = joined_df.where(joined_df.x == 5)
joined_df.write.format("csv").save(path1)
output_df.write.format("csv").save(path2)
```

So, I have 2 actions in the code, both of them make filters on df1 and join the data with df2.
Where is the right place to use cache() in this code?
Should I cache df1 and df2 because they will be used in both of the actions.
Or should I cache only the joined_df that is the last common part between this 2 actions?

Comment: I think the only place worth calling cache on is `df1 = df1.where(df1.city == 'NY').cache()`. Maybe you also want to cache on `joined_df = df1.join(df2, on = "key").cache()` as `joined_df` is used in two subsequent actions. But it's very possible that Spark's own optimizations make this comment invalid in some aspects.

Comment: @ernest_k I expect spark to have full optimization if I cache only the joined_df but I just want to make sure it's true

Comment: You're actually right, I thought `df1` was being used beyond the line declaring `joined_df`. So yes, I'd only have `joined_df = df1.join(df2, on = "key").cache()` in this code. But this only stands if you do *not* use `df1` or `df2` after creating `joined_df`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to cache a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156365/when-to-cache-a-dataframe)

Comment: question is why don't u apply the `joined_df.where(joined_df.x == 5)` filter before the join? `x` is coming from either df1 or df2 (or both..)

Comment: Also, I would consider repartitioning the data if the filters are very limiting and leaves u with an unbalanced dataframe.

Comment: @LiranBo I wrote this code just to understand how caching work in the background. I also could combine some filters together. This code is just example for the question

Comment: My advice is only using caching if it has a great benefit for u. there are just too many downsides for caching - possible disk space issue, AQE (spark 3+) disabled, in many cases it can slow things down. So u need to make sure there's a real performance increase in u'r use case.