# Spark EMR Read from S3 Transform and Write back to S3, Need Performance Improvement

Tags: performance, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

**Using AWS EMR cluster.**

**Scenario :**

1. I need to read inpute parquet files from S3
2. Do some transformation on data, I do it by Spark SQL
3. I need to write output files(multiplart parquet) back to S3.

- Input data volume : 30GB
- Output volume : 500GB

I am using 1 Master - m5.8xlarge and 7 Core nodes of type r5.12xlarge.

I tried writing files direct to S3 in step3 as well as writing to local files and move them to S3.
Writing direct to S3 taking more time.

- Time writing direct to S3 = 5 hr
- Time writing to local and move to S3 = 4 hr

1. I tried with m4.2xlarge Master with EBS of 600GB and 10 Core r5.2xlarge, and tried writing files to /mnt/ path. But, Cluster core nodes fails due to space issue.
   Is there any way, that I can ask Core nodes to write files on Master node's EBS volume ?

As the files total size in Step3 are >500GB, I have to use r5.12xlarge instances. For lower instances, it gives out-of-memory issue.

I am not doing repartition on dataFrame to avoid data suffling. Just doing dataFrame.write.parquet(path)

2. Any other Master/Core/EBS combination for optimal performance  ?

Please suggest best combination for my scenario.

Comment: make sure you are using Amazon's optimised S3 committer, otherwise task  and job commit does file-by-copy which  is (a) unsafe and (b) really slow

Comment: I tried it by changing from s3a to s3, but its giving exception of No FileSystem for scheme: s3.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding repartition is not always good, in the case of data skewness, dataframe reparition will be in your side. See [here](https://databricks.com/fr/session/handling-data-skew-adaptively-in-spark-using-dynamic-repartitioning).

So let's start from your spark job, first you need to analyse your job through spark ui, this will help you to detect any data skewness, shuffling and any other spark related bottleneck. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/web-ui.html).

Also depending to your job, you may need to cache your dataframe, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156828) to check if you really need it or not.

If you have checked all the common spark optimisations, depending to your EMR version check these two configuration and be sure that they are enabled :
[maximizeResourceAllocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html#emr-spark-maximizeresourceallocation) and the [emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer.html)

Comment: Thanks @54I3d For reply. Can you please advise on  Is there any way, that I can ask Core nodes to write files on Master node's EBS volume ? Or at one place in Cluster ? so, I can move them to S3 later.

Comment: @ViralPatel I dont think its a good idea, spark is designed to work in parallel, writing in the same machine is possible but you will not benifit of the power of spark.I advice you to work on enhancing your spark job and your emr config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, will it be better to write output parquet part files direct to S3 ?

Comment: sure ! A well designed spark job with all the points mentioned above, you will get a very good performance !